# Django. Вывод ошибки валидации в шаблон

Tags: django

Подскажите как вывести ошибку ValidationError в шаблон рядом с полем формы которая вызвала ошибку ? сам код правильно обрабатывает проверку, и не записывает то что не надо, но он не выводит это в шаблоне, а просто сбрасывает все поля

forms.py

```
class NetworkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_network(self):
        network_object = self.cleaned_data['network']
        all_object_network = Networks.objects.all()
        received_subnet = ipaddress.ip_network(str(network_object))
        frozen_received_subnet = set(received_subnet)
        for network_in_table in all_object_network:
            subnet_in_table = ipaddress.ip_network(str(network_in_table))
            frozen_subnet_in_table = set(subnet_in_table)
            difference = frozen_received_subnet & frozen_subnet_in_table
            if not difference:
                print('Значение пустое')
            if difference:
                print('Значение не пустое')
                raise ValidationError('asdasdasdasd')
        return network_object


    class Meta:
        model = Networks
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def networking(request, region_id):
    networks = Networks.objects.all().order_by('network')
    networks_for_region = Networks.objects.filter(region_reletionship=region_id)
    form = NetworkForm()
    parametrs = {
                'networks':networks,
                'networks_for_region':networks_for_region,
                'region_id':region_id,
                'form': form
                }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NetworkForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render(request, 'Network_page.html', parametrs)
```

HTML

```
{% block script_and_style %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/network_style.css">
    <script src="/static/JS/JS_for_network_page.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="block">
        <button id="addNetwork" name="addNetworkButton">Добавить сеть</button>
    </div>
    <div id="networkForm">
        <form method="post" id="addForm">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}


{% block table_content %}
 <!--   <caption>Сети</caption>  -->

        {% for network in networks_for_region  %}
            <tr>
                <td> <a href={% url 'address' region_id network.id %}> {{ network.network }}</a> </td>
                <td>{{ network.description }} </td>
                <td><a href={% url 'vlans' region_id %}>{{ network.vlan_reletionship|default_if_none:"---" }}</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

измени код таким образом, что бы в html context у тебя попадала актуальная версия формы. В твоем случае ты постоянно в контекст передаешь форму с пустыми значениями полей. Добавь определение parameters после того, как проверишь был ли `POST` запрос и валидна ли форма

```
def networking(request, region_id):
    networks = Networks.objects.all().order_by('network')
    networks_for_region = Networks.objects.filter(region_reletionship=region_id)
    form = NetworkForm(request.POST if request.POST else None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    parametrs = {
        'networks':networks,
        'networks_for_region':networks_for_region,
        'region_id':region_id,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'Network_page.html', parametrs)
```

что бы информация об ошибке была рядом с полем у которого возникает ошибка замени строку
`raise ValidationError('asdasdasdasd')` на `self.add_error("network", "asdasdasdasd")`

Comment: Спасибо помогло) Подскажите теперь как сделать чтоб ошибка валидации под конкретным полем появлялась, а не вверху формы

Comment: добавил в ответе